# Tag Wiki for [whatever-subject] - is the info about whatever-subject, or that actual tag?

Tags: support, tag-wiki

I find writing the tag snippets rather fun, and I especially try to fill them in when I use a tag that's lacking a snippet. After all, if I'm using whatever it is on the tag, I should know enough about it to write a sentence or two, or at LEAST the wikipedia link to it, right?

But as I review others to get inspiration about the sort of content that should be put into them, I find myself seeing two distinct types of tag snippets. One set describes the word behind the tag. A good example of this is the [Java] tag. But every now and again, I see tags like [jpa-2.0].

Which of the following would be most appropriate?

This, where we describe the actual thing

> Whatever-subject is an open source
>   thingamabob that allows you to
>   incapacitate your flux to ludicrous
>   speed. Written by the reputable Larry,
>   Curly, and Moe consulting, it supports
>   platform independence and caffeinated
>   drinks.

Or this, which describes the tag and its uses

> The Whatever-Subject tag should be
>   used for issues with the
>   Whatever-Subject libraries and their
>   integrations with other LCM libraries.
>   If your question is about general
>   thingamabobs, or simple questions
>   about flux capacitation, use the
>   thingamabob and flux-capacitation tags
>   instead.

I see a bit of both, and I'm not sure there's a standard.

Any insight (or incite, whatever the case may be) on this?

Comment: Ironically, the two tags are `[support]` (which starts "this tag is used...") and `[tag-wiki]` (which describes what a tag-wiki is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen the latter used (especially on Super User) for cases where there might be some confusion over which tag to use. The wiki seems the ideal place to remind people which tag of two similar ones is the most appropriate to use.

An example would be `[windows]` and `[windows-xp]`.

The former tag would be used for general issue with Windows or something that occurred on all versions of Windows, while the latter would be for XP specific problems. Getting this right will help get the question answered.

The former style is more appropriate for unambiguous tags.